# Question about for loop and extracting parts of the name to use borg create command

Tags: bash, shell, debian

I have a folder called sync which includes files like :

```
vzdump-lxc-101-2018_06_07-02_23_11.tar
vzdump-lxc-101-2018_07_20-03_04_22.tar
vzdump-lxc-101-2018_08_17-03_34_11.tar
vzdump-lxc-101-2018_09_17-02_44_50.tar
vzdump-lxc-101-2019_01_19-00_16_02.tar
...
vzdump-lxc-104-2018_06_30-01_50_23.tar
vzdump-lxc-104-2018_07_20-03_18_56.tar
vzdump-lxc-104-2018_08_17-03_40_15.tar
vzdump-lxc-104-2018_10_19-01_52_00.tar
vzdump-lxc-104-2018_11_06-02_39_07.tar
vzdump-lxc-104-2019_01_19-00_24_14.tar
```

Ranging from vzdump-lxc-100 to vzdump-lxc-1xx etc..

I'm trying to loop over all files in a given directory and do a borg create (...) /path/to/repo::vzdump-lxc-$ID-$year_$month_$day "$f" but I'm not sure how to cut the name to just these three points

I tested it with the following : `for f in vzdump-lxc*; do borg create (...) /path/to/repo::srv01_lxc_"$f" "$f";done` , but this gives me the full name which is too long including the leading vzdump-lxc, hour, minute, second and the extension maybe someone could lead me in the right direction.

I'm trying to achieve `/path/to/repo::srv01_lxc_$id_$year_$month_$day`

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split that name using `'._-'` as the input field separator. Something like this:

```
IFS='-_.' read -ra path <<< vzdump-lxc-104-2019_01_19-00_24_14.tar
echo ${path[*]}
vzdump lxc 104 2019 01 19 00 24 14 tar
```

The code above creates an array `path` with all the components split. After that, you can use any of them by referring its index:

```
echo ${path[3]}
2019
```

With that in mind, your code could something like this:

```
for f in vzdump-lxc*; do
    IFS='-_.' read -ra p <<< $f 
    borg create (...) /path/to/repo::srv01_lxc_${p[2]}-${p[3]}-${p[4]}-${p[5]} "$f"
done
```

I hope that helps.